# IOException while checking Internet connection: java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android

I get the error every time I check for internet connection. And yes I have my permissions set up. Please how do I handle the exception?
My code and logcat is provided below:

ConnectionDetector.java:

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

/**
 * Checking for all possible internet providers
 * **/
public static  boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context _context){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null)
    {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Edit: logcat output:

```
06-14 18:41:00.211 2984-14403/com.bluestacks.s2p E/S2P.: IOException while checking Internet connection: 
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to www.apple.com/23.203.89.26 (port 80) after 3000ms
     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
     at com.bluestacks.s2p.G.isNetworkConnected(G.java:193)
     at com.bluestacks.s2p.PingService.onHandleIntent(PingService.java:67)
     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: If there is an exception, it would be helpful to include details of the exception in the question.

Comment: Sorry for that as I am new here. Below is the logcat:

Answer (score 0):

`getAllNetworkInfo()` was deprecated since API 23 as mentioned [here in Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworkInfo()).

A better, cleaner approach for checking for network connection I'd recommend is as follows:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    // TODO: Implement functionality after successfully connecting to the network
} else {
    // TODO: Otherwise, inform the user that network connection failed
}
```

### UPDATE:

After reading your updated post about the logcat error in more detail, I must mention that there's not much you can do for SocketTimeoutExceptions - in other words, it's most likely an **internet connection** problem. That said, the best way to address this issue is to catch the exception (either IOException or SocketTimeoutException) when opening up and connecting to an HTTP server, and then inform the user with UI that internet connection failed. For instance:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.connect();   
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Problem connecting to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem connecting to the internet", e);
} finally {
    if (urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you DaveNOTDavid but I am relatively new in android development. I followed a tutorial online to test and learn better. but so far I/ have not been able to get past this error

Comment: @AceOgbonnaya Ok, let me know how it goes. P. S. I updated the post once more :-)

Comment: do I put this code in the ConnectorDetector.java file?

Comment: please help edit the NewsFeedParser method below:   public NewsFeedParser(String urlString) {
        this.urlString = urlString;
    }

    public static InputStream downloadStream(String urlString) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        return stream;
    }

Comment: alternatively please find the link to the project and please help me figure out to handle the exception: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqlkdhx4ys49ocv/NDtv.rar?dl=0

Comment: @AceOgbonnaya Did you make sure to surround with try/catch blocks wherever you invoked downloadStream()?

Comment: @AceOgbonnaya Here's a sample: https://github.com/DaveNOTDavid/dnd-headlines/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/davenotdavid/dndheadlines/QueryUtils.java